# Running db-sync on a separate machine from node on same LAN

Tags: cardano-node, cardano-db-sync

I currently have cardano-node and db-sync running on the same machine. The machine has a max RAM capacity of 32 GB and this is barely enough. Instead of buying a new machine that supports 64 GB RAM, I could use another machine I have of 32 GB RAM, to run only db-sync, on the same LAN as cardano-node.

I'd like to hear from anyone that has run cardano-node and db-sync both on the same machine as well as on different machines on the same LAN to see if you decided it had to be both cardano-node and db-sync on the same machine because on separate machines proved too slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. Run cardano-node on one of the machines and cardano-db-sync on the other, and use socat to connect from the cardano-db-sync machine to the cardano-node's socket file. This is how I am doing it.

Comment: Thank you. A machine that supports 64 GB RAM is more expensive than many that only support up to 32 GB, so this being an option - using socat, is a great option. I will try it too. Right now I am running without issue since using the  --disable-ledger option at db-sync startup as suggested by RdLrT.

Comment: Is it fairly straightforward to use socat for this purpose? 
I have 2 machines, both with 32 GB RAM, both on the LAN, both running Ubuntu with cardano-node and cardano-db-sync installed and ready to be launched.

Comment: Yes, it is very simple.On the machine where the cardano-node is running, you run this:
`/usr/bin/socat TCP-LISTEN:3081,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-connect:/path/to/your/node.socket`
On the machine with the cardano-db-sync, you run:
`socat UNIX-LISTEN:/run/cardano-node.socket,fork,reuseaddr,unlink-early,user=<your_user>,group=<your_group>,mode=755 TCP:<cardano-node-ip>:3081`
And you will have your socket as `/run/cardano-node.socket` (you can set any path you like). Use the user and the group you are running cardano-db-sync with. You can also use any port you want.

Comment: Thank you for these detailed instructions! Very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

A very big chunk of memory usage for dbsync comes from `ledger-state` - you can disable this component if you do not require things like `epoch_stake`, `ada_pots`, etc.
You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/blob/master/doc/configuration.md#--disable-ledger).

If you do require these, 48GB RAM IMO is bar minimum, and 64GB is ideal (for instance, if you optimise Postgres configurations to serve more processing capacity and less IO dependency)

Comment: Was not aware of those options, I shall examine that, ty!

Comment: "migrating to a no ledger schema"
was reported after relaunching db-sync with the --disable-ledger flag added!

Comment: Appears to work like a charm @RdLrt = thank you!

Comment: That is excellent advice mate. Absolutely beautiful!!!

Comment: I am doing this and the memory usage is MUCH less - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running `cardano-db-sync` on the same machine of `cardano-node`. The machine is also a `block-producer` `(--nonmoving-gc)`, `cardano-wallet` provider, `cncli sendtip` provider. The amount of RAM needed ended up to be **64GB**.

The main reason driving me to host everything on the same machine is that it's a virtual machine that I can fine-tune whenever I want.

Also, you should consider this: `cardano-db-sync` needs a `--socket-path path` specified. That means that you can't straightforwardly run `cardano-node` and `cardano-db-sync` on different machines. You can probably play around with netcat to redirect I/O to/from the socket to/from a TCP socket, or mount remotely the path where the socket is located.

Comment: Thank you - so far the clear winner is still "use a machine that has 64 GB of RAM"